# Anomaly Detection Methods for Clean Training Data

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

The goal is to find anomalies in my dataset, univariant anomaly detection which basically means looking for anomalies only in one column.

Up until this point I have tried DBSCAN; Isolation Forest and K-Means.

Recently I have been told that if the training data is does not have anomalies I can use autoencoders and other methods.

I am a bit confused on what are the other methods that can be used in cases where your training data has no anomalies. You do the training on them and then you run the model on the Test Data and check how good your algorithm is working.

I have been trying to find articles and papers regarding this but most of them don’t talk or say if the training data does or doesn’t have anomalies.

Comment: Do you have a dataset with a target (a 0,1 variable that say that yes this is actually an anomaly or not after further investigations) ? What would be an anomaly in your univariate data set ? Extreme values ? Spike in density ?

Comment: @lcrmorin, I have two options. Add some anomalies to the dataset manually like 5% or 10%  off to what the min or max of the data that is found on the column.  2nd Option: This is part of this question. Traing the algorithm on  dataset that has no anomalies but then comes the question which I have made. Which are algorithms that you can  do the training on clean/no anomaly data